# CapsNet - Connection between ReLU Conv1 and PrimaryCaps

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

Hinton's paper *Dynamic Routing Between Capsules* (https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.09829) describes how we might use capsules for image recognition with dynamic routing.

In particular, the architecture first uses a classic convolutional layer (*ReLU Conv1*) with 256 feature maps. The output of this layer is then received by a capsules layer (*PrimaryCaps*) and later by a final capsules layer (*DigitCaps*).

My question is about the link between *ReLU Conv1* and *PrimaryCaps*. In the paper, we read:

> The second layer (PrimaryCapsules) is a convolutional capsule layer with 32 channels of convolutional
>   8D capsules (i.e. each primary capsule contains 8 convolutional units with a 9 × 9 kernel and a stride
>   of 2). Each primary capsule output sees the outputs of all 256 × 81 Conv1 units whose receptive fields overlap with the location of the center of the capsule. In total PrimaryCapsules has [32 × 6 × 6]
>   capsule outputs (each output is an 8D vector) and each capsule in the [6 × 6] grid is sharing their
>   weights with each other.

It is unclear to me whether this means that for a given capsule (8D vector) in *PrimaryCaps*, the first element of the vector gets input from all the local convolutional units in *ReLU Conv1* (much like a fully-connected layer) or that the first element of the vector receives input from convolutional units $1:32$, the second element from units $33:64$ and so on (which would resemble a convolutional logic). Both kinds of connections seem to satisfy the postulate:

> Each primary capsule output sees the outputs of all 256 × 81 Conv1 units whose receptive fields overlap with the location of the center of the capsule.

I would appreciate any thoughts on that.